# matrix manipulation in java OOP

Tags: java

This code gives me  errors at lines 153, 158 and 163 stating"variables not found". i need to print them using the menu but not sure if this is working. help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



class Matrix {

double[][] element;
int rows, cols;

Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    element = new double[rows][cols];
}

public double getValue(int row, int col) {
    return element[row][col];
}

public void setValue(int row, int col, double value) {
    element[row][col] = value;
}

public int getNoRows() {  // returns the total number of rows
    return rows;
}

public int getNoCols() { // returns the total number of cols
    return cols;
}

// The methods for the main calculations
public Matrix AddMatrix(Matrix m2) {
    int row1 = getNoRows();
    int col1 = getNoCols();
    Matrix result = new Matrix(row1, col1);

    for (int i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col1; j++) {
            result.setValue(i, j, this.getValue(i, j) + m2.getValue(i, j));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public Matrix MultiplyMatrix(Matrix m2) {
    if (this.getNoCols() != m2.getNoRows()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("matrices can't be multiplied");
    }
    int row2 = this.getNoRows();
    int col2 = m2.getNoCols();
    Matrix result = new Matrix(row2, col2);
    for (int i = 0; i < row2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col2; j++) {
            result.setValue(i, j, result.getValue(i, j) + this.getValue(i, j) * m2.getValue(i, j));
        }
    }
    return result;

}

public Matrix TransposeMatrix() {
    int row3 = this.getNoCols();
    int col3 = this.getNoRows();
    Matrix result = new Matrix(row3, col3);
    for (int i = 0; i < row3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col3; j++) {
            result.setValue(i, j, this.getValue(j, i));
        }
    }
    return result;

}

public void DisplayMatrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getNoRows(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.getNoCols();
                j++) {
            System.out.print((this.getValue(i, j)) + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
  }
 }



 public class Lab1 {

 public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

    int choice;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    Boolean loopcont= true;
    while (loopcont){   
    System.out.println("1. Add two matrices \n");
    System.out.println("2. Multiplymatrix two matrices \n");
    System.out.println("3. Take transpose of a matrix \n");
    System.out.println("4. Display a matrix \n");
    System.out.println("5. Exit \n");

    System.out.println("Enter your choice \n");
    choice = in.nextInt();

    switch (choice) {

    case 1:{ 
        System.out.println("For the first matrix");
        Matrix m1 =  MatrixReader();
        m1.DisplayMatrix();
        System.out.println("For the second matrix");
        Matrix m2 =  MatrixReader();
        m2.DisplayMatrix();
        Matrix m3 = new Matrix(m1.getNoRows(), m1.getNoCols());
        m3 = m1.AddMatrix(m2);
        m3.DisplayMatrix();
        break ;
    }
    case 2:{
        System.out.println("For the first matrix");
        Matrix m1 =  MatrixReader();
        m1.DisplayMatrix();
        System.out.println("For the second matrix");
        Matrix m2 =  MatrixReader();
        m2.DisplayMatrix();
        Matrix m3 = new Matrix(m1.getNoRows(), m2.getNoCols());
        m3 = m1.MultiplyMatrix(m2);
        m3.DisplayMatrix();
        break;

    }
    case 3:{
        System.out.println("For the first matrix");
        Matrix m1 = MatrixReader();
        m1.DisplayMatrix(); 
        Matrix m3 = new Matrix(m1.getNoRows(), m1.getNoCols());
        m3 = m1.TransposeMatrix();
        m3.DisplayMatrix();
        break;
    }
    case 4:{
        int printInput;
        System.out.println("What matrix do you want to print?");
        printInput = in.nextInt();
        switch(printInput){
        case 1:{    
        System.out.println("Printing Matrix m1");
        m1.DisplayMatrix();
        break;
        }
        case 2:{
        System.out.println("Printing Matrix m2");
        m2.DisplayMatrix();
        break;
        }
        case 3:{
        System.out.println("Printing Matrix m3");
        m3.DisplayMatrix();
        break;
        }
        default:{
        System.out.println("Invalid Input. please enter again");
        break;
        }
    }
}   
case 5:{
      loopcont= false;
      break;
}
    default:{
        System.out.println("Incorrect input. Kindly enter again \n");
        break;
     }
    }
 }
}

public static Matrix MatrixReader() throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Give the filename for the matrix");
    Scanner filescanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filescanner.nextLine()));
    scanner.nextLine(); // removes the first line in the input file
    String rowLine = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] arr = rowLine.split("=");
    int rows = Integer.parseInt(arr[1].trim());

    String colLine = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] arr2 = colLine.split("=");
    int cols = Integer.parseInt(arr2[1].trim());
    Matrix test = new Matrix(rows, cols);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            test.setValue(i, j, scanner.nextDouble());
        }
    }


    return test;

   }
}
```

Comment: Could you please indicate which lines those are? For example by adding a comment on those lines. Also, posting the **exact** error message is usually useful.

Comment: do tell us which lines those are. There's no line numbers when using code tags.

Comment: this is one of them:   Lab1.java:163: cannot find symbol
                       symbol  : variable m3
                       location: class Lab1
 it's the m3.display func in case 4

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

Under **Case 4:** variables **m1, m2, m3** are not initialized.

```
    Matrix m1;
    Matrix m2;
    Matrix m3;

switch (choice) {
    case 1: {
        System.out.println("For the first matrix");
        m1 = MatrixReader();
        m1.DisplayMatrix();
        System.out.println("For the second matrix");
        m2 = MatrixReader();
        m2.DisplayMatrix();
        m3 = new Matrix(m1.getNoRows(), m1.getNoCols());
        m3 = m1.AddMatrix(m2);
        m3.DisplayMatrix();
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        System.out.println("For the first matrix");
        m1 = MatrixReader();
        m1.DisplayMatrix();
        System.out.println("For the second matrix");
        m2 = MatrixReader();
        m2.DisplayMatrix();
        m3 = new Matrix(m1.getNoRows(), m1.getNoCols());
        m3 = m1.MultiplyMatrix(m2);
        m3.DisplayMatrix();
        break;

    }
    case 3: {
        System.out.println("For the first matrix");
        m1 = MatrixReader();
        m1.DisplayMatrix();
        m3 = m1.TransposeMatrix();
        m3.DisplayMatrix();
        break;
    }
    case 4: {
        int printInput;
        System.out.println("What matrix do you want to print?");
        printInput = in.nextInt();
        switch (printInput) {
        case 1: {
            System.out.println("Printing Matrix m1");
            m1 = MatrixReader();
            m1.DisplayMatrix();
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            System.out.println("Printing Matrix m2");
            m2 = MatrixReader();
            m2.DisplayMatrix();
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            System.out.println("Printing Matrix m3");
            m3 = new Matrix(m1.getNoRows(), m1.getNoCols());
            m3.DisplayMatrix();
            break;
        }
        default: {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input. please enter again");
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    case 5: {
        loopcont = false;
        break;
    }
    default: {
        System.out.println("Incorrect input. Kindly enter again \n");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I don't want to call the MartrixReader method again. Is there a way around it then?

Comment: there is no MatrixReader method! correct me if i am wrong, did u meant the MatrixReader object initialization? if so, in which case?

Comment: yeah that's what i meant. i'm sorry not really familiar with the exact terms. I want to avoid giving the filenames again for m1 and m2.

Comment: i'm sorry. according to your code MatrixReader is a method, but i mistook it as a class..!!!

Comment: For all the cases you need m1 and m3. So initialize it before the switch statement. Initialize m2 only in the cases you need the second call. Refer the edited answer.

Comment: this does not quite solve the problem as MatrixReader is still executed in order to print the matrices under the 4th case (the one with 3 sub switch cases).

Comment: but this stops working properly if i put in a wrong input. it will still execute MatrixReader and then realize the number inputted was wrong. I tested it out.

Comment: what is the input you are giving? what output did you got?

Comment: Try implementing it with if/else if/else blocks. That would be a better way of implementation.

Comment: The input is 7. it should show me the error message instead it just prinrs out "enter the filename" and then shows the error mssg.

Comment: it gives me more errors now saying that m2 is already declared.

Comment: i have removed the intermediate declaration of m2 variables. Now check the edited answer!

Comment: error on line 165. Lab1.java:165: variable m1 might not have been initialized
            m3 = new Matrix(m1.getNoRows(), m1.getNoCols());
                            ^

Comment: initialize m1 object before that line. Use this one, m1 = MatrixReader();

Comment: i realize after all of this...i'm right where i started. still can't get aorund not using MstrixReader

Comment: i think there is nothing to do technically, but you need to change the implementation in order to comply with functionality you want.!

Comment: where the MatrixReader not to be used?

Answer (score 0):

If you tired to write your own code with matrix, just download library I developed. It can add, multiply, invert, transpond, calculate determinant and solve linear systems.

please check: [Linear Math Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linearmath/)

This is open source you can download the source code too and look how in works.